# Add and remove Grid rows at runtime

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create a layout with a grid, where you have a "+" Button to add a new row to enter stuff and next to every new row a "-" Button to remove that row.

[image: example image]

I've googled far and wide and have not found a single thing above removing XAML Grid rows at runtime.

The static layout on startup:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="GridSource">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="lblSource0" Text="Source:" Margin="5" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="cmboSource0" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="CmboSource_SelectionChanged" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Name="txtSource0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="5" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Name="btnSource0" Content="..." Width="50" Margin="5" />
    <Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Name="btnAddSource" Content="+" Width="50" Margin="5" Click="BtnAddSource_Click" Height="32" />
</Grid>
```

The logic to add and remove rows:

```
private void BtnAddSource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AdditionalSourceCounter++;
    string Name = "Source" + AdditionalSourceCounter.ToString();
    GridSource.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()); //add new row to Grid
    Grid.SetRow(btnAddSource, GridSource.RowDefinitions.Count); //move "add Source"-button to last row

    TextBlock newLabel = new TextBlock();
    newLabel.Name = "lbl" + Name;
    newLabel.Text = "Source:";
    newLabel.Margin = new Thickness(5);
    GridSource.Children.Add(newLabel); //add new object to form
    Grid.SetColumn(newLabel, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(newLabel, AdditionalSourceCounter);

    ComboBox newComboBox = new ComboBox();
    newComboBox.Name = "cmbo" + Name;
    newComboBox.Margin = new Thickness(5);
    GridSource.Children.Add(newComboBox); //add new object to form
    for (int i = 0; i < Data.SourceTypes.Count; i++) //add items from SourceTypes-list to ComboBox
        newComboBox.Items.Add(Data.SourceTypes[i]);
    newComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    newComboBox.SelectionChanged += CmboSource_SelectionChanged;
    Grid.SetColumn(newComboBox, 1);
    Grid.SetRow(newComboBox, AdditionalSourceCounter);

    TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();
    newTextBox.Name = "txt" + Name;
    newTextBox.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
    newTextBox.Margin = new Thickness(5);
    newTextBox.IsReadOnly = true;
    GridSource.Children.Add(newTextBox); //add new object to form
    Grid.SetColumn(newTextBox, 2);
    Grid.SetRow(newTextBox, AdditionalSourceCounter);

    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Name = "btn" + Name;
    newButton.Content = "...";
    newButton.Width = 50;
    newButton.Margin = new Thickness(5);
    GridSource.Children.Add(newButton); //add new object to form
    Grid.SetColumn(newButton, 3);
    Grid.SetRow(newButton, AdditionalSourceCounter);

    Button newButtonRemove = new Button();
    newButtonRemove.Name = "btnRemove" + Name;
    newButtonRemove.Content = "-";
    newButtonRemove.Width = 50;
    newButtonRemove.Margin = new Thickness(5);
    newButtonRemove.Click += BtnRemoveSource_Click;
    GridSource.Children.Add(newButtonRemove); //add new object to form
    Grid.SetColumn(newButtonRemove, 4);
    Grid.SetRow(newButtonRemove, AdditionalSourceCounter);
}

private void BtnRemoveSource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AdditionalSourceCounter--;
    var callingButton = (Button)sender;
    int rowNumber = Grid.GetRow(callingButton);
    int callingButtonIndex = GridSource.Children.IndexOf(callingButton);
    GridSource.Children.RemoveAt(callingButtonIndex);
    GridSource.Children.RemoveAt(callingButtonIndex - 1);
    GridSource.Children.RemoveAt(callingButtonIndex - 2);
    GridSource.Children.RemoveAt(callingButtonIndex - 3);
    GridSource.Children.RemoveAt(callingButtonIndex - 4);
    GridSource.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(rowNumber);
    Grid.SetRow(btnAddSource, GridSource.RowDefinitions.Count);
}
```

Adding rows is working but removing the rows has ... interesting results. First most notably the "+" Button covers the last "-" Button so the whole thing becomes unusable and I don't know why...
The target is that the layout remains as in the screenshot above so you can add and remove rows as much and anywhere you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the row of the add button to `GridSource.RowDefinitions.Count`. However, this is one more than the number of rows that actually exist in your `Grid`. Rows are counted from 0 to `Count - 1` so instead the last row is `GridSource.RowDefinitions.Count-1`. What happens is the `Grid` can't find the row with index `Count` so it just puts the button in row `Count-1`, hence the button covers the `-` button on last row.

If you check your static code, you can see you have one additional row only for the plus button. You have to replicate this here as well.

Furthermore, if you remove a row in the middle of the `Grid` you correctly remove its items but you also need to shift all next elements one row up - so you need to decrease their `Grid.Row` property by one.

```
private void BtnRemoveSource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AdditionalSourceCounter--;
    var callingButton = (Button)sender;
    int rowNumber = Grid.GetRow(callingButton);
    int callingButtonIndex = GridSource.Children.IndexOf(callingButton);
    foreach ( var child in GridSource.Children.ToArray() )
    {
        var childRow = (int)child.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        if (childRow == rowNumber)
        {
            //this child should be removed
            GridSource.Children.Remove(child); 
        }
        else if (childRow > rowNumber)
        {
            //move items on next rows one row up
            child.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, childRow - 1);
        }
    }
    GridSource.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(rowNumber);
    Grid.SetRow(btnAddSource, GridSource.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
}
```

Note that instead of this long and error prone code, you might consider either using `StackPanel` where each item would be a `Grid` with just one row and the columns matching your current code - in this case you could just remove the whole item from `StackPanel` and would not have to care about fixing the `Row` values and `RowDefinitions`.

Even better - you could rewrite the code to a `ListView` with custom `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your comprehensive answer! I thought about giving up and using a stack panel. Problem is: if I use different grids, the columns wouldn't have the same width, right? That would look horrible. I never used data templates is this something that would solve my Problem?

Comment: Well depends on how you size the columns. If you use star sizes, or absolute sizes for all columns, the sizes will be the same as there is the same available space. Auto is more problematic, but if all auto cells contain the same things on all rows, then you will be ok

Comment: Listview with data templates is just more convenient, as you just provide the data and the control will generate the items with the templated controls automatically. Removing rows is then as simple as deleting the item from the bound collection. It is fairly complex topic however, so I suggest looking through the documentation, especially the ListView and Data binding topics

Comment: I will definately check out DataTemplates. I don't want to write unnessaccary complicated code after all. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: Glad it helped :-). Happy coding!